# Rails Action Cable not working since upgraded from 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I upgraded my Rails app from 5.1.4 to 5.2.1 and Action Cable was worked fine but is not working since upgraded.
Websocket seems to be working correctly, but Channel won't start transmitting and streaming.

My development server has no problem since worked with Rails 5.1.4 and a blank app with Rails 5.2.1 worked correctly includes action cable on my development server.

I have no idea why channel won't start.

Log worked fine with Rails 5.1.4.

```
Started GET "/cable" for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-10-10 15:33:41 +0900
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-10-10 15:33:41 +0900
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vc2lzL1VzZXIvMQ)
CommentChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
CommentChannel is streaming from comment_channel_3
CommentChannel#speak({"comment"=>"43", "commentable_id"=>3, "user_id"=>1})
  Group Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `groups`.* FROM `groups` WHERE `groups`.`inappropriate` = 0 AND `groups`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `comments` (`body`, `commentable_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `commentable_type`) VALUES ('43', 3, 1, '2018-10-10 15:33:45', '2018-10-10 15:33:45', 'Group')
```

Log  Rails 5.2.1. Logs about CommentChannel doesn't show up.

```
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-10-11 15:13:56 +0900
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb:14
Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vc2lzL1VzZXIvMQ)
Started GET "/cable" for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-10-11 15:14:09 +0900
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-10-11 15:14:09 +0900
```

app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      if current_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
        current_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

app/channels/comment_channel.rb

```
class CommentChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "comment_channel_#{params[:id]}"
  end

  def unsubscribed; end

  def speak(data)
    # update comment
  end

  def read(data)
  end
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/cable.js

```
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();
}).call(this);
```

comment.js

```
App.cable.subscriptions.create( {channel: 'CommentChannel', id: $('#comments').data('commentableId') }, {
  connected() {},
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected() {},
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received(data) {
    this.perform('read', { group_id: $('#comments').data('commentableId') });

  },
  speak(comment, commentable_id, user_id){
    return this.perform('speak', {comment, commentable_id, user_id});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line was the problem. After delete this line it works fine.

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```